# JHipster and Google Cloud Platform

Tags: jhipster

I've just deployed a cluster on google cloud platform kubernete engine using JHipster. The deploy worked fine and the main application starts, but the underground microservices doesn't work. I always have an "Internal server error" when i click on a button that calls a microservices. I tried to allow visibility between nodes but it still doesn't work. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: What do you see in gateway logs for the internal server error?

Comment: What version of JHipster are you using?